# GLSL imageStore slower on uimageBuffer than on uimage2D?

Tags: performance, opengl, glsl

I have a #version 420 GLSL vertex shader that writes to a texel (always the same one) of an uimage using the imageStore function. (In the actual release version, I use more than one texel, so this setup is just an extreme test case for performance measuring.)

I tried two different ways:

- writing to an 'layout(r32ui) coherent uniform uimage2D',
  i.e., I bound a GL_TEXTURE_2D to the image unit
- writing to an 'layout(r32ui) coherent uniform uimageBuffer',
  i.e, I bound a GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER to the image unit, which itself has a VBO with GL_STATIC_DRAW bound)

In a test scene with 360K vertices, for both alternatives I measure different performances (The vertices are simply rasterized as GL_POINTS, so the fragment shader effort is neglectible):

- shader without imageStore: 2.1 ms
- const-coord imageStore to uimage2D: 2.1 ms
- const-coord imageStore to uimageBuffer: 3.2 ms

So, it seems that imageStore to an imageBuffer is somehow slower than to an image2D. But it gets worse. If I don't imageStore to a fixed texel with constant coordinate as above, but use a dynamically determined offset, the I get these performances:

- dynamic-coord imageStore to uimage2D: 2.1 ms
- dynamic-coord imageStore to uimageBuffer: 7.2 ms

Can anyone confirm this performance difference, or explain why writing to a uimageBuffer is so much slower than writing to a uimage2D? Is it because of the VBO bound to the Buffer-Texture? Or do I seem to have done something wrong?

I also should mention that the vertex shader also uses a second uimage2D for some atomic counting stuff, but that is the same for each case and should have nothing to do with the imageStore.

Comment: "*the VBO bound to the Buffer-Texture*" You cannot bind a VBO to a buffer texture. You can bind a *buffer object* to a buffer texture. VBO is a *use* of a buffer object, not the object itself.

Comment: What are you using to determine the performance of these thing? Also, why are the variables `coherent`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and sorry for the late reply!
Actually, you're right, I think the 'coherent' layout is unnecessary here. I measure it with a simple CPU Performance-Timer, but make a glFinish before I take the time. Maybe there is an more exact way I'm not aware of, but still, the uimageBuffer version is constantly slower in all my measurements.